# REGEXP in Teradata SQL

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a column in a table which has text like "ADDED EMAIL ADDRESS FROM CTCE DATA 21FEB", RMESTIMATE0, 'REQUESTED TKT NUMBERS ON 21FEB' etc. As they are manually entered remarks they don't have any maximum character length. I am required to exclude the date part in the text (like 21FEB) from the column. The date part is at the end (some of them don't have ddmmm at the end) but I cant do a SUBSTR here because the length of the comment is not fixed (no max or min). Can REGEXP help in this case? ideally the result would be "ADDED EMAIL ADDRESS FROM CTCE DATA","EQUESTED TKT NUMBERS ON" "RMESTIMATE0" etc for the values in the column

Comment: Is the date always DDMMM?

Comment: Yes the date is always DDMMM in the column

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEXP_REPLACE to remove the date portion, e.g.

```
RegExp_Replace(x, ' [0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{3}$','',1,1,'i')
```

*Remove a space followed by one or two digits followed by three characters at the end of the string*

or

```
RegExp_Replace(x, ' [0-9]{1,2}(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)$','',1,1,'i')
```

*Remove a space followed by one or two digits followed by a three character month abreviation at the end of the string*

Comment: Thanks dnoeth!  Both of the REGEXP's  worked for 90% of the data in the column..But not if the data is like this "TREX AUTO REFUND 1843/22FEB". Both the REGEXP's return the entire comment along with the date(MMDD) after the / at the end

Comment: The 1843 is a time stamp in text.I am trying to remove 1843/22FEB and just return "TREX AUTO REFUND"

Comment: I was able to get it removed by using the below REGEXP
RegExp_Replace(X, ' [0-9]{1,4}/[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{3}$','',1,1,'i')

Comment: To catch both variations you should make the time part optional: ' ([0-9]{1,4}/)?[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]{3}$'

Comment: Thank you it worked. I have few values in my data like 'REVIEWED BY DATA ANALYST XXXXXXXXXXXX' and 'FF XX XXXXXXXXX'. I am trying to write a REGEXP_REPLACE for this to return just 'REVIEWED BY DATA ANALYST' and 'FF XX'. Just the 1st four words in the first example and the first two words in the second example and ignore the rest. Can you please help?

Comment: For this case I wouldn't use Regexp_Replace, but `RegExp_Substr(x, '(REVIEWED BY DATA ANALYST|FF XX)')`

Comment: I did for the first case alone REGEXP_SUBSTR(X, '(REVIEWED BY DATA ANALYST )') and it came up  with '?'

Comment: @Jude92: There's a space after ANALYST. Or it might be a case-sensitivity issue, try `RegExp_Substr(X, '(REVIEWED BY DATA ANALYST)', 1, 1, 'i')`